# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request Visual Code

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to connect to my Sharepoint Online Site Collection with the help of Visual Code and I am getting below error -The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Code-

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\dlls\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\dlls\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$userName = "***"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force

$webURL="https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/"
$Context=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webURL)
$Context.Credentials=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$password)
$Web=$context.Web
$Context.Load($web)
$Context.executeQuery()
Write-host $Web.URL
```

Comment: your code is fine, i am able to run this in Windows powershell and VS Code with powershell extension installed. However, you may try downloading SharePoint online client components and reference the installed dlls 
`Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
 Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" `

Comment: I have installed the latest dlls but still same issue :(. I have enabled powershell ISE mode as well.

Comment: have you tested this in powershell?

Comment: Yes and it is working on Powershell ISE.

Comment: try uninstalling and installing powershell extension in VS code again

Answer (score 0):

If installed the latest SharePoint Online, please check in there is dlls in this folder:

[image]

And then in Visual Studio install PowerShell Plugin:

[image]

Then it should able to run as expected, this is the result in my side:
[image]

Comment: I have done everything which has been mentioned above but still same error. May be I am missing some configuration. God Knows why?  :(

Comment: Can you run the script in PowerShell ISE ? In my side, Visual Studio Code only install PowerShell plugin and save the code as ps1 file, then able to run and debug.

Comment: Uninstalling the visual code, restarting the machine and installing again worked for me.